# Cannot find module with **/*.test.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, glob, node.js-tape

I'm trying to set up testing for my Next.js project. I want to test it with RITEway which is based on tape. I want a `test` command that finds all files in my `src/` folder that end with `.test.js`.

Here is the commend I came up with:

```json
"test": "NODE_ENV=test node -r @babel/register src/**/*.test.js",
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/project/src/**/*.test.js'
```

How can I tell node to find all files ending in `.test.js` in my `src/` folder?

**Extra context:**

My testing files live in `src/features/<feature>/<feature.test.js>`, e.g.:

```json
"test": "NODE_ENV=test node -r @babel/register src/features/home/home-page-component.test.js",
```

Works to find a single file and run it.

```json
"test": "NODE_ENV=test node -r @babel/register src/**/**/*.test.js",
```

Works to find all folders in features, but ignores files like `src/<file>.test.js`, which I also want to run.

I had to install `@babel/register` and `@babel/core` for Node to process absolute imports and newer syntax.

My `.babelrc` is:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "root": [
              "."
            ],
            "alias": {
              "features": "./src/features"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Comment: The `node` command only takes one script to run, and doesn't accept a regex (or glob, as that pattern actually is is). Per [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/riteway#troubleshooting) you want to use the riteway cli.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I tried that. Running `"test": "NODE_ENV=test riteway -r @babel/register src/**/*.test.js",` (is that what you mean?) finds files on lower levels `src/<file>.test.js` but then doesn't run the deeper nested files like `src/features/home/home-page-component.test.js`, but I want to run all `.test.js` files.

Comment: Note that the docs suggest you should *quote* the glob - you want to pass it to `riteway`, rather than letting your shell expand it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That works! Thank you very much! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Sharpe said, you have to feed the regex into `riteway`.

```json
"test": "NODE_ENV=test riteway -r @babel/register 'src/**/*.test.js'",
```