# Run glob command in TypeScript (TS-Node)

Tags: node.js, typescript, glob, ts-node

A couple months earlier, I asked [how to feed a glob into a Node pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63978695/cannot-find-module-with-test-js). I wanted to run tests in [RITEway](https://github.com/ericelliott/riteway) and the solution was to run the command with `riteway` instead of `node`.

```json
"test": "NODE_ENV=test riteway -r @babel/register 'src/**/*.test.js'",
```

Now I converted the project to TypeScript. Running the command above (after changing `.js` to `.ts`), throws the following error:

```
$ NODE_ENV=test riteway -r @babel/register 'src/tests/**/*.test.ts' | tap-nirvana
/Users/user/my-proj/src/tests/fn.test.ts:1
import { describe } from 'riteway';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/user/my-proj/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at /Users/user/my-proj/node_modules/riteway/bin/riteway:54:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

After Googling, I think I have to use `ts-node`, but that command has the same problem as just running `node`.

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ NODE_ENV=test ts-node -r @babel/register 'src/tests/**/*.test.ts' | tap-nirvana
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/my-project/src/tests/**/*.test.ts'
```

How can I feed the command to RITEway, but make it work with TypeScript?

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Could you also post your `tsconfig`?

Comment: @Titulum Done! :)

Comment: Could you give me your  `type` in `package.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run transpiled typescript by registering `ts-node/register/transpile-only` in your `riteway` command:

```sh
"test": "NODE_ENV=test  riteway -r ts-node/register/transpile-only 'src/**/*.test.ts'",
```

Also make sure that the `module` option in your `tsconfig` is set to `commonjs`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "next-env.d.ts",
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx"
    ]
}
```